# Need to limit the current date by the end of previous month in Power BI Slicer

Tags: powerbi, filtering, dax, measure

I have a report in Power BI Desktop, with the slicer - YearMonthSort - which has data selection by Year-Month

Plz, see the screenshot below:

[image]

My goal is to limit data in this slicer as - **to the end of previous month**.

For example, if today is 8/21/2019, I need my Report to show data until  07/31/2019.

And, since I have it in the "Year-Month" format, it should be limited (displayed as **2019-07**)

When I needed to limit this slicer by today's date I used

```
IsToday = SWITCH (TRUE (),'Dimension Date'[Date] <= NOW (), 1, 0)
```

(by StackOverflow advice)
What, if I need it to be limited until the last day of the previous month?

Thank you!

Comment: Look into EOMONTH(NOW,-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would create a calculated column similar to this one:

```
IsLDPreviusMonth = SWITCH (
                     TRUE (),
                     'Dimension Date'[Date] <= EOMONTH( NOW(), - 1), 
                     1, 
                     0
)
```

[EOMONTH](https://dax.guide/eomonth/)

Comment: I did exactly as you've described even before this post, but my Slicer has "All" option (even after I set "Show Select All option" to Off mode in Selection Control of my slicer).  I guess, there is no way to remove that "All" choice. That was confusing, and I thought my formula was not correct or not complete.   But you've confirmed otherwise!

Comment: @Hell-1931 if you (as you should ) filter date on the report/page level, "Select all" option should not be a problem